# Initialize Git repo in TFS using RestAPI

Tags: git, rest

Is there a way to initialize Git repo after creating it using TFS rest-api? I want to see if this can be automated instead of clicking on the Initialize button.  THank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll1xx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Get into the directory of your repo and do this:

git init